# How can I hide a cable from a lamp in my room

Tags: electricity, cables, bedroom

In my room I have got a lamp and have a frustrating cable hanging against the wall. How can I hide the cable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use [*surface wiring*](http://www.familyhandyman.com/electrical/wiring-outlets/how-to-add-outlets-easily-with-surface-wiring/view-all).
2. Run the wire through the ceiling and/or wall; it's not difficult, in most cases, but should be inspected by an electrician if you do it yourself.
3. Conceal it with something such as [*fake beams*](http://www.homedepot.com/b/Building-Materials-Moulding-Millwork-Faux-Wood-Beams-Mouldings/N-5yc1vZc1mj).

Comment: An electrician will not sign off on #2 - you can't run power cables through a wall or ceiling unless it's proper home wiring that terminates at a junction box. You'd have to install a new junction box and outlet near the lamp, it's against code to run a lamp cord through the wall to a nearby outlet.